# How to produce output in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

This is my data :

```
  NASIDENTIFIER TERMINATECAUSE   avg_dur  avg_input avg_output total
         (fctr)         (fctr)     (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl) (int)
1       BSRAS01   Lost-Carrier  37221.89   61267475  846641401    87
2       BSRAS01    NAS-Request 259205.00 2011644584 3118623049     1
3       BSRAS01   User-Request  12329.50   38958653  461478822    60
4       BSRAS51    Admin-Reset 206589.99  589002948 5989044994   140
5       BSRAS51   Lost-Carrier  36059.12  157811318 1837199576 33990
6       BSRAS51    NAS-Request 259209.07  267715474 3123280566    28
```

How can i produce plot with x(terminatecause) and y(total) based on each of `nasidentifier`?

This is my code:

```
library(shiny)

#UI.R
ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Testing"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("nas", "Your NAS-Identifier",levels(NASIDENTIFIER))),

  mainPanel(

    plotOutput("nasplot")
  )
))

#SERVER.R
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$nasplot<- renderPlot({
    plot(q$TERMINATECAUSE,q$total)
  })
})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Are you looking for a multi-facet plot (one plot for each of the identifier)?

Comment: yes.as i change the nasidentifier in the browser,it will produce different plot

Comment: Just need to add a filter before plot. `q <- df[df$NASIDENTIFIER == input$nas,]`, assuming your data is `df`.  Also change `levels(NASIDENTIFIER)` to `levels(df$NASIDENTIFIER)`.

Comment: this is what i got warmoverflow.Error in switch: EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Comment: Are you hell bent on producing individual plots from each level? If not, try using `ggplot2::facet_wrap()`.

Comment: yes im trying to produce individual plot from each nas

Comment: warmoverflow u are right.sorry for late notice.mine have switch command

Comment: The example you provide is not very informative. On top of that, it's not really a shiny issue since we don't know how you mean to show/save these plots. Can you elaborate?

Comment: sorry im new here.just want to produce shiny with my own data.usually example given is based on own created data

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see what the result should look like. To me it would appear `facet_wrap` kind of solution would solve the problem, but you don't appear to address this comment.